# How to use convert,in,and split conditions in one line

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In my web application the following abbreviation allows me to input a value and choose its type within the application e.g. `:input`

In this case I created a variable `:grades` as a varchar (You will understand why I chose this as varchar)

The teacher wants to know who received a grade of 2 or 3, maybe more

e.g. 2,3 -- She wants to know who got a grade of 2 and who got a grade of 3

So I produced the following code to just do that!

```
 where gc.idx in (cast(regexp_split_to_table(:grades, ',')) as integer)
```

This obviously didn't work and I assume that's because this splits into a table and not into a string. How can I make this expression work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't split into a table, convert it into an array and use the `= any` operator with an array.

```
where gc.idx = any (string_to_array(:grades, ',')::int[])
```

If for some strange reason your "web app" doesn't allow the `::int[]` notation, you can use a `cast()` expression:

```
where gc.idx = any (cast(string_to_array(:grades, ',') as int[])
```

Comment: Since im using a web app, that expression ::int is not compatible with the coding! That was the sacrifice for the input and its not possible to change!

Comment: but i try array like u said

Comment: What does the "web app" have to do with the SQL code? But if your programming environment is so limited, try a `cast()` - see my edit

Comment: like always horse! I love you!